# Recuperar Id do Auto Incremento DataSnap Delphi XE3

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, cliente-servidor, datasnap

Utilizo Delphi XE3 / DataSnap com Firedac

Quando mando gravar a tabela pai no servidor quero recuperar o valor que foi adicionado via auto incremento no pai para que eu possa informar este novo valor na chave estrangeira na tabela filha.

Nao sei onde pegar e como pegar se pode ser em que evento.

```
...AfterUpdateRecord(Sender: TObject;
  SourceDS: TDataSet; DeltaDS: TCustomClientDataSet; UpdateKind: TUpdateKind);
```

**ou**

```
...BeforeUpdateRecord(Sender: TObject;
  SourceDS: TDataSet; DeltaDS: TCustomClientDataSet; UpdateKind: TUpdateKind;
  var Applied: Boolean);
```

Comment: [Isso](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/20847) que você quer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No servidor (TADQuery e TDataSetProvider), no evento 'AfterPost' do TADQuery Master deve ser executado o comando Refresh que será atualizado com o ID do autoincremento que acabou de ser executado "Criei uma variavel FId : Integer para receber o valor retornado do banco para uso no dataset filho"

Conforme exemplo abaixo:

```
procedure TsrmNFSe.ADQueryAfterPost(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
   ADQuery.Refresh;
   FId    := ADQuery.fieldbyname('id_campo_autoincremento').AsInteger;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

A maneira mais indicada de você fazer isso é fazendo uso  evento `[BeforeUpdateRecord][1]`. Neste evento você pode alterar o Delta que está sendo enviado para o banco (controlando até mesmo o tipo de alteração que está acontecendo. Você pode guardar o novo ID dentro de uma variável private do DM (ou do objeto principal) e depois utilizá-la nos itens.